# Passing an ng-model value to an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list made with ng-repeat with options. I'm trying to make it so that when I click an option, the value of the selection will be passed to an object.

```
<select id="selectvak" name="selectvak" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="1" ng-repeat="t in klas" ng-model="vakselect">{{ t.Name }}</option>
</select>

$scope.user = {
vak: klas.vakselect,
};
```

I have small experience with Angular, so I'm not sure how to make it work correctly.

Edit:

I have adjusted my code and user.vak does seem to catch the selectvak field, but now passes it as an array. How do I make it so it's a string in $scope.user? So whenever I log user, I will see a string of vak and then an array of students.

```
<select id="selectvak" name="selectvak" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" ng-model="user.vak" ng-options="t.Name as t.Name for t in klas" ng-click="getJSON1()">


 $scope.user = {
vak: '',
// klas: klasselect,
student: [$scope.student] -1
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLJ and Arnaud are correct.
But answering your initial question, in the select tag, instead of `ng-model="vakselect"` just use `ng-model="user.vak"`.
Then, when the value of the select changes, the value of `user.vak` will change automatically.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far, but when I am logging vak in my console, it will log it as empty.

Comment: Try logging `user.vak`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It returns user.vak as empty.

Comment: A better example using `ng-change` and the attribute `size` in the select to don't allow the user to select multiple options: http://jsfiddle.net/k58Hw/274/

Comment: I have tried your original way (having ng-model in an option form) and the second way (ng-model in select form), but it returns to an array both times. How do I make it into a string?

Comment: The second exemple on JSFiddle is returning the value as a String, please, take a look. You have to remove the `multiple="multiple"` attribute and add the `size="5"` attribute (being 5 just an example, you can change this).

Comment: This seemed to work, thanks! There is however one small thing left. After changing multiple="multiple" to size="5", the first option in the form seems to be empty as shown in https://i.imgur.com/wfsUJ34.png . Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: In your controller, just do something like this: `$scope.user = { vak: 'initValue' };`

Answer (score 0):

real code is this : (and nothing to do inside the controller.

```
<select id="selectvak" name="selectvak" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"  ng-model="user.vak">
    <option value="1" ng-repeat="t in klas">{{ t.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

And you should use `ng-options` instead of ng-repeat to create your options
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Using ng-options will make the form into a dropdown, which is what I don't want. The format right now is for an open list.

Comment: If you use select, you must use ng-option to fill it instead of ng-repeat.

Comment: I think it is a Bootstrap format that changes it into an open form. Angular uses this form: https://i.imgur.com/Ztkaxmm.png while Bootstrap uses this form: https://i.imgur.com/SA0i0IQ.png
I have entered select ng-options accordingly, but it uses a combobox.

Comment: add `multiple="multiple"` on the select.

Answer (score 0):

This will add t.name to an array when you click the option. Take a look at the controller function and the ng-click in the partial.

```
  <select id="selectvak" name="selectvak" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="1" ng-repeat="t in klas" ng-click="add(t.Name)" ng-model="vakselect">{{ t.Name }}</option>
    </select>

    var string_option;
    $scope.add = function(t) {
        string_option = t; 
        console.log(string_option )
    }
```

Comment: Do I have to push it into an array? Is it not possible to make it into a string?

Comment: you mean a string with all the elements inside the array?

Comment: I am trying to select 1 option and pass the value of the selected option into a single string, not the entire list.